# Run SVN repository preview on localhost

Tags: localhost, tortoisesvn

I am using tortoise SVN to upload my code to the server. The problem is I have to commit my code every time before seeing the output in browser. Is there a way by which I can run the repository on localhost and finaly when the code is completed I can commit the code to server.

Comment: Can't you set up a local WAMP/LAMP server?

Answer (score 0):

You can install a WAMP server: http://www.wampserver.com/en/

There are a multitude of tutorials online how to do it.

Then you place your code in the correct directory (preferably in the `www` folder). You link your application to index.html similarly as I assume you have already done on the server you are using now.

You can then test your application by navigating to `localhost` in your browser.

Once you are satisfied with everything, you can migrate it to your server with SVN.

Comment: @LazyBadger I don't understand the issue. He can install a wamp and use it as the working copy, and when done commit it. Isn't that exactly what **run the repository on localhost** means? To have a local working copy and able to test it locally

Comment: Alternatively it should be possible to serve the content of the repository locally by modifying the server configs to point at the local directory path; ie. usually there's no need to copy things about for testing.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on the host OS, check into Apache or Nginx if ya want fully featured web server and change the listen address to either `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` and if only for local tests you can set a listen port greater than `1024` to avoid running the server in a privileged user account.

Also consider `nc` or `netcat` as a built in option

```
Var_port=4444
Var_www_dir="/var/www/host_one"
Var_index_file="index.htm"
cd ${Var_www_dir}
while true; do
    nc -l ${Var_port} <${Var_index_file}
done
```

Leave above running in a terminal while testing then use Ctrl^c later to quit the while loop.

Or if you already have php installed, most dev systems end up with it installed at some point, and prefer to only listen on the localhost

```
cd ${Var_www_dir}
php -S localhost:${Var_port}
```

For testing multi page sites I think using php will be less prone to server oddities causing errors, really nc should be avoided if you've the option.

Comment: That is what is described above, localhost serving of local system. Perhaps you should read up on the offered solutions a bit more because both mine and the other are valid ways of accomplishing what the OP wants.